# A question about interior.

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Let $X$ a topological space. Let $A,B$ and $C$ subsetes of $X$.

> If $$A\subseteq\text{Int}(B\cup C)$$
>   Under what conditions can we say that $\text{Int}(A)\cap\text{Int}(B\cup C)\ne\emptyset$?
>
> Could you give me some examples and / or counterexamples?

Thanks!

Comment: By $Int(A)$, you mean "interior of $A$"?

Comment: @NazimJ Yes, $\text{Int}(A)$ is, for me, equivalent to $A^{\circ}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want $\mathrm{Int}(A) \cap \mathrm{Int}(B \cup C) \neq \emptyset,$ the first requirement is that $A \neq \emptyset,$ this also prevents $\textrm{Int} (B \cup C)$ from being empty. The next condition needed is that $\textrm{Int} (A) \neq \emptyset.$ With these two conditions we have that $\textrm{Int} (A) \subseteq A \subseteq \textrm{Int} (B \cup C)$ where $\textrm{Int} (A)$ is non empty. From the above inclusion we have $\mathrm{Int}(A) \cap \mathrm{Int}(B \cup C) = \textrm{Int} (A) \neq \emptyset.$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $Int(A) \neq \emptyset$.  We know that $Int(A) \subseteq A$, so we always have
$$ Int(A) \cap Int(B \cup C) \neq \emptyset $$
The only way for this to fail is if $Int(A) = \emptyset$ or $Int(B \cup C) = \emptyset$